# Git - How to merge two local disconnected repositories

Tags: git

Consider the following scennario:
Two different machines and local repositories (A and B) contain the same project.  Work has progressed at different pace on both repositories and currently B is most current. Machines A and B are not networked.

1. It is desired to merge B into A, preserving the history of both A and B. Work will then continue for a while on A.
2. After some additional progress on A, it is desired to merge A onto B, preserving histories to later continue work on B.

Is this possible? What operations are necessary to perform on A and B to fulfill requirements 1 and 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your repositories both clones of the same original repository? Do they have a shared history that has diverged?

Comment: Look at `git bundle` which allows using "sneakernet" to transfer data between repositories which can't talk to each other. Or, if you're able to somehow transfer repos from machine to machine, Git is fine with fetching changes from "local URLs" like `/path/to/a/repo.git`.

Comment: @alexbclay The project was started without source control, and backups were copied from one machine to the other.  Then git was implemented without server access, just local repositories (no sync) but development and master branches are used.  I want to be able to work on either machine A or B and then merge both repositories preserving the histories.

Comment: @kostix.  Thank you.  I will give it a try.

Comment: @David, do I understand you correctly that one of the repos contains the "master" branch and another one contains the development branch? Or does each repo contain both?

Answer (score 1):

If the servers can talk to each other, you can set each repo to be a remote for the other

```
you@A> git remote add origin_b A:/path/to/repo.git

you@B> git remote add origin_a B:/path/to/other/repo.git
```

Then each repo can fetch each others branches to merge and branch as necessary.  If branch names interfere with each other, you can rename them to be more specific.

Another way would be to create a new centralized repo that both servers use as the source.

This link has some good info on git workflows:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows